# SQL LIMIT VS Loop Limit

Tags: php, sql, count, while-loop, limit

I was browsing around Stack Overflow attempting to find how to limit an SQL query with a while loop and I came across this code.

```
$count = 0;

while ($count < 4 && $info = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    //stuff

    $count++;
}
```

**Q 1:** What is the difference between this code and using the SQL `LIMIT` clause?

**Q 2:** For what reason would somebody want to use this code, rather than using `LIMIT`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. With this code, the MySQL server will send all the results to the client, but the client ignores everything after the 4th row. So the server has to do more work, and more bandwidth will be used between the client and server.
2. They might want to use `mysql_num_rows()` to find out how many total rows were selected, even though they only want to display the first 4. However, MySQL provides a way to do that with `LIMIT` -- you can put the `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` option in the `SELECT` clause, and then use `SELECT FOUND_ROWS()` to get the total number of rows. So there's no good reason, except they don't know about this feature.

Answer (score 0):

Everyting @Barmar said is right on.  Following with code like that will cause lots of problems as your result sets start to grow.  Let a database do what its good at doing, let it supply the limit of results you want/need.  Just think of what happens when you do a SELECT with no LIMIT clause in the command line client where there are thousands of rows...it just goes on and on.

One more thing, I wouldn't recommend using mysql_num_rows() as its a deprecated function.  Might as well go along with mysqli or PDO.